# Grouping data in a SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, merge, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

In developing an SSRS 2008 R2 report, I'll like to show some data grouped by values, while merging others, I've run into a problem doing this on report builder.

```
|               Parent Group            |
|_______________________________________|
|Group A|Group B|Group C|Group D|Group E|
|_______|_______|_______|______|________|
|    5  |   2   |   1   |   1  |   5    |
|    4  |   2   |   4   |   2  |   2    | 
|    1  |   3   |   1   |   3  |   2    |
```

Can I create a filter or grouping to combine Group C, D, E together while leaving A and B alone?

Like such,

```
|        Parent Group         |
|_____________________________|
|Group A |Group B|Other Groups|
|________|_______|____________|
|    5   |   2   |     7      |   
|    4   |   2   |     8      |   
|    1   |   3   |     6      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

**SQL query**

Usually the best way to get the result you want is to let SQL do the heavy lifting:

```
SELECT GroupA, GroupB, (GroupC + GroupD + GroupE) AS OtherGroups
FROM MyTable
```

**In the report**

If you can't change your query result (for example, it is a stored procedure) then you can do the same thing in SSRS VB code.

Right-click the cell and choose `Expression...` and enter something like the following:

```
=Fields!GroupC.Value + Fields!GroupD.Value + Fields!GroupE.Value
```

and `SUM` in the same way:

```
=SUM(Fields!GroupC.Value) + SUM(Fields!GroupD.Value) + SUM(Fields!GroupE.Value)
```